# repeating fields in avro (python)

Tags: python, schema, avro

I am trying to use avro in python to serialize XML data. I can figure out the optional field coding, but how do I do repeated fields?

For example, given this schema, how do I make favorite_number a repeated field so that someone can have more than one favorite_number?

```
{"namespace": "example.avro",
 "type": "record",
 "name": "User",
 "fields": [
     {"name": "name", "type": "string"},
     {"name": "favorite_number",  "type": "int"},
     {"name": "favorite_color", "type": ["string", "null"]}
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [specification](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.6/spec.html#schemas), maybe something like this...

```
# For example, a linked-list of 64-bit values may be defined with:

{
   "type": "record", 
   "name": "LongList",
   "aliases": ["LinkedLongs"],                      // old name for this
   "fields" : [
       {"name": "value", "type": "long"},             // each element has a long
       {"name": "next", "type": ["LongList", "null"]} // optional next element
   ]
}
```

Or you could use an array...

```
# Arrays use the type name "array" and support a single attribute:
#
# items: the schema of the array's items.
# For example, an array of strings is declared with:

{"type": "array", "items": "int"}
```

Additionally, you can nest records [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764287/how-to-nest-records-in-an-avro-schema).

Comment: It looks like an array is right, but there are several kinds. I found this & am working through the thread right now... http://apache-avro.679487.n3.nabble.com/Schema-for-array-of-records-td2710382.html  
Here is what I ended up with:
{"namespace": "example.avro",
 "type": "record",
 "name": "User",
 "fields": [
     {"name": "name", "type": "string"},
     {"name": "favorite_number", "type": {"type": "array", "items": "int"}},
     {"name": "favorite_color", "type": ["string", "null"]}  
 ]
}