# Avro Namespace Error

Tags: namespaces, avro

i have a question.
I made the following avro schema:

```
{
          "namespace": "foo",
          "fields": [
            {
              "type": [
                "string",
                "null"
              ],
              "name": "narf"
            },
            {
              "namespace": "foo.run",
              "fields": [
                {
                  "type": [
                    "string",
                    "null"
                  ],
                  "name": "baz"
                }

              ],
              "type": "record",
              "name": "foo"
            }
          ],
          "type": "record",
          "name": "run"
        }
```

When i try to compile this i get the following error:

/usr/bin/python3.4 /home/marius/PycharmProjects/AvroTest/avroTest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/marius/PycharmProjects/AvroTest/avroTest.py", line 11, in 
    schema = avro.schema.Parse(open("simple.avsc").read())

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/avro_python3_snapshot-1.7.7-py3.4.egg/avro/schema.py", line 1283, in Parse
    return SchemaFromJSONData(json_data, names)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/avro_python3_snapshot-1.7.7-py3.4.egg/avro/schema.py", line 1254, in SchemaFromJSONData
    return parser(json_data, names=names)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/avro_python3_snapshot-1.7.7-py3.4.egg/avro/schema.py", line 1182, in _SchemaFromJSONObject
    other_props=other_props,

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/avro_python3_snapshot-1.7.7-py3.4.egg/avro/schema.py", line 1061, in **init**
    fields = make_fields(names=nested_names)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/avro_python3_snapshot-1.7.7-py3.4.egg/avro/schema.py", line 1173, in MakeFields
    return tuple(RecordSchema._MakeFieldList(field_desc_list, names))

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/avro_python3_snapshot-1.7.7-py3.4.egg/avro/schema.py", line 986, in _MakeFieldList
    yield RecordSchema._MakeField(index, field_desc, names)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/avro_python3_snapshot-1.7.7-py3.4.egg/avro/schema.py", line 957, in _MakeField
    names=names,

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/avro_python3_snapshot-1.7.7-py3.4.egg/avro/schema.py", line 1254, in SchemaFromJSONData
    return parser(json_data, names=names)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/avro_python3_snapshot-1.7.7-py3.4.egg/avro/schema.py", line 1135, in _SchemaFromJSONString
    % (json_string, sorted(names.names)))

avro.schema.SchemaParseException: Unknown named schema 'record', known names: ['foo.run'].

And i have no idea why. In my mind the error is the record called "foo" but the namespace i gave ("foo.run") is in the namespacelist but ut raises an error anyways. I guess i misunderstand something regarding namespaces but i could not figure out what.

Greetings 
Marius

Answer (score 0):

Ok found the error, is generated this schema with my own program and it had a bug when a nested record appears within a nested record. #
See: [How to nest records in an Avro schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764287/how-to-nest-records-in-an-avro-schema)