# Nesting Avro schemas

Tags: nested, schema, record, avro

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764287/how-to-nest-records-in-an-avro-schema) on nesting Avro schemas, the right way to nest a record schema is as follows:

```json
{
    "name": "person",
    "type": "record",
    "fields": [
        {"name": "firstname", "type": "string"},
        {"name": "lastname", "type": "string"},
        {
            "name": "address",
            "type": {
                        "type" : "record",
                        "name" : "AddressUSRecord",
                        "fields" : [
                            {"name": "streetaddress", "type": "string"},
                            {"name": "city", "type": "string"}
                        ]
                    },
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't like giving the field the name `address` and having to give a different name (`AddressUSRecord`) to the field's schema. Can I give the field and schema the same name, `address`?

What if I want to use the `AddressUSRecord` schema in multiple other schemas, not just `person`? If I want to use `AddressUSRecord` in another schema, let's say `business`, do I have to name it something else?

Ideally, I'd like to define `AddressUSRecord` in a separate schema, then let the type of `address` reference `AddressUSRecord`. However, it's not clear that Avro 1.8.1 supports this out-of-the-box. This [2014 article](http://www.treselle.com/blog/advanced-avro-schema-design-reuse/) shows that sub-schemas need to be handled with custom code. What the best way to define reusable schemas in Avro 1.8.1?

**Note**: I'd like a solution that works with Confluent Inc.'s Schema Registry. There's a [Google Groups thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/confluent-platform/pey5-AS1NSE) that seems to suggest that Schema Registry does not play nice with schema references.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Can I give the field and schema the same name, address?

Yes, you can name the record with the same name as the field name.

> What if I want to use the AddressUSRecord schema in multiple other schemas, not just person?

You can use multiple schemas using a couple of techniques: the avro schema parser clients (JVM and others) allow you to specify multiple schemas, usually through the `names` parameter (the Java `Schema$Parser/parse` method allows multiple schema `String` arguments).

You can then specify dependant Schemas as a named type:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Address",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "streetaddress",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "city",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

And run this through the parser before the parent schema:

```
{
  "name": "person",
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "firstname",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "lastname",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "address",
      "type": "Address"
    }
  ]
}
```

Incidentally, this allows you to parse from separate files.

Alternatively, you can also parse a single Union schema that references schemas in the same way:

```
[
  {
    "type": "record",
    "name": "Address",
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "streetaddress",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "city",
        "type": "string"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "record",
    "name": "person",
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "firstname",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "lastname",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "address",
        "type": "Address"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

> I'd like a solution that works with Confluent Inc.'s Schema Registry.

The schema registry does not support parsing schemas separately, but it does support the latter example of parsing into a union type.

Comment: Hi Niel, I am trying exactly the same schema on confluent cloud, but when I am calling this schema in producer I cannot use this schema, i.e., `<ccloud kafka topic produce sometopic --delimiter ":" --value-format "avro" --schema "./above_schema.avsc" --sr-endpoint "https://xxxx.eu-central-1.aws.confluent.cloud" --api-key "xx" --api-secret "xxxxx"
Starting Kafka Producer. ^C or ^D to exit
{"firstname": "Joe", "lastname": "Doe", "address": {"streetaddress": "somestreet", "city": "somecity"}}
Error: cannot decode textual union: cannot decode textual map: cannot determine codec: "firstname"

Comment: Your schema which is a JSON array did pass the avro validation but how can it be used? The producer's calling syntax that works on JSON object schema does not work on your proposal. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can set `namespace` to the record type and then, in subsequent fields, use `{namespace}.{name}` as the `type` argument. Unfortunately currently there is no possibility to reference types from other schema files.

Comment: I tried nesting an avro as a type but it doesn't find the type defined in another schema file even in 2023 with avro maven plugin 1.11.1. Is this a unsolved mystery ? Appreciate if someone solved this problem to comment.

Comment: @Knp from what I know it's still unsolved and being honest I wouldn't expect it to be solved in the future as well. Maybe if you use avdl files, required types will be nested in the avsc. From what I understand, `avsc` files have to be self-contained as they are included in the header of `.avro` files.

Answer (score 0):

Just like **@Niel Drummond** rightly said. You can nest avro schemas defined in separate files...

Using the same example he used:

**Assuming we have these two schemas defined in separate avro files.**

```
let the file path be ${project.basedir}/src/main/avro/schemas/Address.avsc
{
  "namespace": "com.nesting",
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Address",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "streetaddress",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "city",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

This schema references the Address schema in the "address" field.

```
let the file path be ${project.basedir}/src/main/avro/schemas/Person.avsc
{
  "namespace": "com.nesting",
  "name": "Person",
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "firstname",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "lastname",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "address",
      "type": "Address"
    }
  ]
}
```

If you get this error during compilation `Undefined name: "Address"`
Then check that you have your avro plugin configured to import the **Address** schema as shown below.

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
        <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>schema</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/avro/schemas/</sourceDirectory>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/avro</outputDirectory>
              <imports>
                <import>${project.basedir}/src/main/avro/schemas/Address.avsc</import>
                <import>${project.basedir}/src/main/avro/schemas/Person.avsc</import>
               
              </imports>

              <includes>
                <include>*.avsc</include>
              </includes>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

And your code should work with the above configuration.

**NOTE:** The Avro plugin version used here is **1.11.1**