# avro.schema.SchemaParseException: Unknown named schema 'record', known names: ['<namespace_name>.<name>']

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, schema, avro

I have a nested JSON structure as shown below. When I do avro.schema.Parse using python3 I get an error.

```
avro.schema.SchemaParseException: Unknown named schema 'record', known names:[data.info]
```

```html
{"namespace" : "data",
 "type": "record",
 "name": "info",
 "doc": "A  list  of strings.",
 "fields": [
    {"name": "DATE", "type": "string"},
    {"name": "file", "type": "string"},     
    {"name": "info", "type": "record", "fields": [
            {"name": "START_DATE", "type": "string"},
            {"name": "END_DATE", "type": "string"},
            {"name": "other", "type": "array", "items":"string"}]}
          ]
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with the nested avro sctructure,
I could solve this by follwing [Avro-nested schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40854529/nesting-avro-schemas%3E) 
Also using [avro-json-validator](https://json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com/avro.jsp) could help to find the problem as soon as we write the .avsc files. A successful conversion to JSON tells that the avro.schema.Parse would work fine.I validated the next further updates I did to the .avsc file using this which worked fine.